# How to convert an Eclipse managed cdt project into Makefiles

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile, build, eclipse-cdt

I have a managed C project developed on Eclipse and I would like to convert this project into Makefiles.

I found the Makefiles already generated by Eclipse in debug folder but I saw a warning in the file saying that I should not edit this file.

How can I convert my project easily? I don't want to start from the scratch. It would be perfect if I start it by modifying already generated Makefiles.

My build settings are:

- Properties -> Builders

  - CDT Builder (ticked)
  - Scanner Configuration Builder (ticked)
- Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Tool Chain Editor -> Current toolchain: Linux GCC
- Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Tool Chain Editor -> Current builder: GNU Make Builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never tried it, but in principle it should be as simple as making a copy of the generated makefile under another name (typically, `makefile` or `Makefile`), and making a few changes in Project Properties -> C/C++ Build:

- Under "Builder type", change "Internal builder" to "External builder" (if it isn't that already)
- Uncheck "Generate Makefile automatically"
- Make sure the "Build directory" is the directory containing your makefile
- If you want, you can also customize the name of the target in the "Behaviour" tab